# React upload file but cannot open the file after selected the file

Tags: reactjs, express, upload

I am trying to upload the two fields plus a file from react to backend express. But I don't know why if I put the value={statement} into the form, when I selected the file, after clicked "open" the file, nothing shows in the browser, but after I removed the value={statement}, "open" the file and the filename is showed.
The thing is how can I reference value after submitting the form?? If I removed the value, there is a network error showing 400.

```
<div className="control">
            <input
            type="file"
            className="input"
            value={statement}
            onChange={changeHandler}
            placeholder="Bank Name"
        />
```

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 1):

It ends up that I placed the placeholder there when the input type ='file'